# Why does Spring RestController adds trailing '=' to body string?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url-encoding

I'm implementing Spring controller that consumes `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in request body:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/serv", produces = "application/json")
public class AccessController {
  @RequestMapping(value="/login", method= RequestMethod.POST, consumes={"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
  public String login(@RequestBody String input, HttpServletResponse resp, HttpServletRequest req){
    ...
  }
}
```

The body content looks like this: 
    `username%3Dalice&password%3Dsecret`
The "input" parameter value is
    `username%3Dalice=&password%3Dsecret=`

Trailing **=** sign appears.
Does anybody know how to get rid of this sign?

Comment: Apparently Spring sees `password%3Dsecret` as the key and adds an = sign afterwards. The `=` on the other hand shouldn't be escaped, so try to use the plain version of it and see if it works.

Comment: Is there any (technical) reason you are using the request body and don't access the post params by `@RequestParam`?